# JSON decode is not working with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a WAMP server with PHP 5.4.3 version. I encoded the data in JSON by php file below is the code (submit.php).

```
$username = 'User';
$comment = 'Test comment';
$date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");  
$image = '/img/sephiroth.png';

  $return = array(
  'username'=> $username,
  'comment' => $comment,
  'date' => $date,
  'image' => $image  );
  echo json_encode($return);
```

Now i have a javascript file(script.js).

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                    alert(result); //It is showing all the JSON data.
                    $value = result;
                    $data = json_decode($value,true);
                    alert($data);
                        }
           });
```

I want to decode all the JSON data separately. e.g Username, comment, date, image. So, i can show them on webpage, at the moment all data is coming together. I tried multiple times with multiple options (php array or result.username or result['username'] but no luck.

Now i am getting below error.

```
ReferenceError: json_decode is not defined
    $data = json_decode($value,true);
```

Comment: you don't have to decode to display it but why do you have php var in your javascript

Comment: `json_decode()` is a PHP function isn't it?  `success: function (data) { alert(data['username']); }` should works

Comment: My bad i am using PHP command in javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. Don't know why it get down voted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot use `json_decode` in JS json_decode is PHP function

use `jQuery.parseJSON(json_data)` to parse your json data;

```
jQuery.parseJSON( result );
```

Change

```
$value = result;
$data = json_decode($value,true);
```

To :

```
jQuery.parseJSON( result );
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: don't even need to use parseJson...jQuery does it internally if Content Type header is set or `dataType:'json'` is set in $.ajax. Much easier as you don't have to catch parsing errors yourself

Comment: Thanks Noman. I will do that. One more thing how can i show decoded data. e.g Username

Comment: let suppose if your json data like `{ "username": "John" }` then you can get the `username` like  `data =  '{ "username": "John" }' ;
var parseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert( parseData.username);`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
success: function(result){
         var res = $.parseJSON(result);
         var data = [res.username, res.comment, res.date, res.image]; // Array of the received response
}
```

This way you can get required output

Answer (score 1):

try like below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
                alert(result); //It is showing all the JSON data.
                jQuery.parseJSON( result );
                    }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataType option of ajax and set its value to json. 
Then you can access the response as result['username']

Answer (score 0):

My example:

Server-side returns `{"username":"xxxxx","data":"xxxxxxxxxxxx and more"}`

You can just deal with json like a javascript array, do not need to decode it.
the `data`  below itself is the array of result.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           var username = data['username'];
           var data = data['data'];
           //and so on
        }
       });
```

**And make sure php sent the header `Content-Type:application/json`**

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`